# jQuery Error load base64 image in Chrome: ERR_INVALID_URL

Tags: image, google-chrome, canvas, base64, filereader

This is a normal jQuery program that use jQuery AJAX post to get data from server, and the data include a full base64 image string generated using `FileReader()`.

Problem:

```js
// It does not work.
var base64blob = "data:image/png;base64,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…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";

var image = document.createElement('img');
    image.src = base64blob;
    document.body.appendChild(image);

// It works.     
var myImg = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,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';
var image = document.createElement('img');
    image.src = myImg;
    document.body.appendChild(image);
```

In this JS Fiddle you can see 2 base64 image string, one success (JPG) and one fail (PNG).

In Chrome the error is `ERR_INVALID_URL`.

Here are what I tried, and all **DOESN'T WORK**:

- Change from `src` to `ng-src`
- Add `==` at the end
- Use `canvas`, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34196173/1802483)
- Reduce the image size to around 330KB (originally 1.2MB)

I am using:

- Chrome 59.0.3071.115
- Win 7
- jQuery 1.12.4
- HTML5

Can anyone please help me on this?

**Update**

[JSFiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/alucard001/w7gxaxbr/)

And the Image I am uploading:
[image: The image I am uploading]

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: Hi gaand, not sure if I understand you correctly because this is generated directly from `FileReader()`, I have added a JSFiddle for that.  You may want to take a look.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

You should **NOT** store your image as a `base64`string in your database. You should convert it to a `byte[]`and save it as a `blob` in your database. It will not cause any problems with the length of the column and will increase performance since the `blob` will not get index as a `string`.

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9723588/3037607).

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR;** The database field `text` is too small for base64, use `mediumtext`.

I found the answer:

- First of all, the true question should be: after uploading the image and converting it to base64, it is saved to MySQL.  Then later on when the same base64 string is fetched from MySQL, the image cannot be displayed properly.
- There is no problem on uploading, or the JS that converting the image to base64.
- **The key problem is that the database field that stores the base64 is too small.**
- Originally I use `text` as MySQL field type, it is still too small (64K in total).  When I change it to `mediumtext`, it works perfectly.

**Check your database**.  Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// It does not work.
var base64blob = "data:image/png;base64,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…k85iO9aBzb8j23QVVYl1jVOEaxHVK622vKTM1HKsgqGYWOS1+hMUrqaLlaceRJ0ZkKAZKo7qZT0lYlHh6ZZC3293A0LrP6p5/9/Ml7zzuhBhqW0TsGqFJDRPr7a+vDILa6ME72v1SWIJ7hukQocfnlHyBXIKeSBaN43SBi42qatq9ISKJGdeZ5VN9vcC+oAdkSXu4JWJeVhmp/dabh+QFWS1FVcnESYCQP0pSRhC5ux7JAZUZEXCl/27FtWImOlwRChGASHREJSCG1zKvbm02y9QTQ2OnifGu0fUeO7e6GMBc6neDfdSZZRZJl7FxJKRPvEhweR8cnlK9t2ulk9sH779/ezpNdauGDuE6rLlHX8jzfbrcIwxT2NPQsieMNKsgu3iET4zvQWrppcH3UVUFJZ4obu8Htg8e3uJ2XReH7PkpIagnRmbxCQS3UOjpmyP3WUd6bjpC8LapRoxphXSuRD8WT77gc7QruCX+NGy1Nb3aEqd2OwOZa/hC51hgH6O3NPKHgfo7w74fRs+fPq6KOtyIv3HZlluOSGb8qiY0Ey2iyEwkPi4bD2fGRPxygYo63G6TEFG7oBEwsZhb4ZF4UHB4d/+DjH+Azr26XJnm6ksTo+h2BW38ITOzuTiv94XHcqb4814g5GA7xMTPRYFL6aLh7k/EYuwlZOI26uZot5NujwRAlOJ09Gq1EgrZNyqzU2V+V8g6fBkvIcPBhaKnk+khrOCUxjXS3y7NCyR2bND/G7RpgsVBJbl+p6/02MfoBpgwdDBkSyWBbK6v81evzzWp9dHDw3tkjVNjK287zmH3hQTakpZoG1g+XIwLebnF7mySJjZzJCyzLubq62a7WnucdTqdWp2VJalvGcIhQZybbzLbCjz784ZPHz/GdgYeUI/R9T1cNg/2MUG3e+7Sj23s47O/tQyyoChnqXmv62+Hwnn6s628VXyqmfMfaTn/n5FH/frNI/V1h/o9jcO6+/c2vd/yiBdLZ0RG2G2WKKfRAHLZUHnQxwyfNiiIrspurS9d1nz49i+N13VaS32kuBft5BmHtWDqO9chzfOTVqOEWi9Xh4aHsW3wDssxE7KmJFEyT7OXLC4QDxEIh7nS27udZx6C1KwokqylCIrnRrcgDC2u5QCl3NBuNRwER9l1N5e6iSXdY6uViGa/W+TZOd2m12ZVFpeetsWVvTpsdnxyePMmzarNY8extLK2mPpLY3TdS1ah2B9eypnxjNJkEtI5TnIy101P/zOjCtFuV9Q6x0DY91whcK0IU84NJ27qsFRtUghXWXl7GZbU2zLyjgjRhIDSK1QXhLgovWLEIeAiEXZdZRoc8UBRdStPG35CFaZika1gsDLj7EDbyssALBMiyHevwYIY9f3l5RRCEbRJZY+h5hiCtTZjXd0WWIjQgLT06OkY5gfvzs8/+ZjY7xCYVMy7C7cXWXZWBprjkGL1+jWzy/Q5/eDDtJY7EGMWUnEFTNG5Dl5mUJiVyq3LvVnBahmPrYguuGW6pm41uNYQYUWfHo1uUSUEOJMV9pkqapmU7dYXMulB9zLZPWUUHTldqcIpjpgumlFjYliAa3kGmBaxHizSJmZYZ2nYbv3z9CnFIxqWWoBlNOa1VM4DVQU2EoApUlLjENZw+Pjs+PqGumGEkSXp4cBT5QbzeJnGCUHF8eLxCVbXeEqvj2mTvJTHJO7SPoJ7gcDahFKflILbttjFeH+vK9yPU/kEQlmIi7zmeKB0SJoSML0VorJs8yXAQMwIitNiOZzti+8K0Ru40DitkG1jbWBuk33piy4yHkipdaXYpenaT0i81KVwt+mempkybB5PRJo5ffvU1XnkUjeM1PlH20UefPHv6PNltl6t5HG+RH+D8xeHbD/FUPJK3Z4UqQu4Ozt7B4ODkWGzzWhRA1JrvSEhyvYAzCU2vcW5kxcFkOr9ZxCvcLkuVqpqmPzChuP+PoUQzFKHwYTiUGbeyFUzpwrjN2W2uqYiLYt1mDY2avndzYheBkDZUVzg+kBbt1pssTqjRVxEjgGVFmr9pBYPxe+9/8OTZ+64fkiyVpIubm91ui5OOMlQU8WGLZjQaB45PJF0iuok9vcjopevFRcUUCzRJr1qkmkHkIzrhXdabdbxa4iLxpK7OL3bxFifq9AAJ1QxfpqB8FQTKIZapk9KwEtYu+coJHslm3ZaVpWku1ppr50WKjObs9Oxgdnhy/Oj0dMZpco/k6QQ/3Dct1QZWK0Hf9zEf6HPrb5WAnfbQseq+LFfai++uF/X7ku67xEJd+1Yp0e8bC/8ZjXwRC48PDnjGWRReY9pjKmMwiiDrho3UEEsQ5/3z99+r26xuCrnPOnnubFUp5SpdrF1c2pWb1u3tAn81Go3KKvMDb7lcVlWBgqAs6ixF0lmyANCoN4azviCcr4u36Wq+Q7HVUJCwQLStiV7UEZWLMq2a3PGs0Yg6+o1MH5C5xrtyudotF+vz1zfLZbzZbPEiu6TMKy3Jy01SFF2X1E1nUrl3Nb+t85Qj787k8U2ebyN9DoUoEU89jg5tZZzWsY86tHQXkXxXloWxbjRUA50okHH189N6QVG3ZO/WadciCOWNlutGjo1vmI2MPqiFj6NSGdQwEvL24BzMTKMR3ZiKksp0Ylc1uSaQopbUXUkyEA+ykpkEsgjcrMlkjCM8SRO8XDQIaF7qOaiEqI2HBFajQDMOAYuezAO6BGjOT3/y12EQiexiv317Hx19b1LXB0BDxWpFTzX2AdHctyV0hbWR8lYpxCuDubZVDjoCRJX2I7XuENQZf1yGHdNDVYvf4xCiwBmxlbbo34m0rCBF1WAJtQse1S5O5PwVEcW2H2PKy9LlXnHvccKzLpSuXS2AUrHoIj0RaXieIUEqXl9cJGJCydaiw6EduedEyvadOhJABY0qgweieW3Hff/DD4aj4fnr8yzh9O6HH3+KeHTx6hz3NYl3qPbiOEbFZogWEa45yXa+9J/xyAaT8eTgEGnW+cvXlKmkjIkxGU6jMMpyrA3EJMpVIyhqYgqIChkJG4sw6qgWDINERXWzydTSTCqLikGgJjQ+MV7gqEuETkm8x4fGgYvYoMjyjXwSMZ2gWUojQi1swglRknNV4RKxcI5TW/fef++jyeTg7PHZ1eX5F1/8Lgy9Tz/9mM2WtkVelaeZqGgze7KFMivVvFhqOhYeR5KnsynPdqyoPE+rsiTlhKZv4iYotoEalW7I5qhkw/emgF0/83kj5VKGmXfGvtrewE5R+zSFXRXZ4z3i3xTTYIJvKcuk/MjYQK+pSZtmOyRFOwqXlwWJYg3pUcggEIdGs+lwiq9DZLOD4QBb5vbmdjmfo5KrC9q9laT243ij/lArcwhbElqRq+WYg/aZtkj12Uq2g8tZeCglO/80sORKxLWh4r+9vMzSlLU+Z4sVwtrR0QnyLd4raXe0NNayXFGC10y7pXHsbrNe6zT1dJ6cHv/NX31wdHi02qwnk8lPPvvxDz5+PpuOxOxM3Ym2kdReBSblb6O8ZXrzSK17iy94F9zezZnQ3xDCVtH0zfpv/3PfzSlC/yNY1H9psfB0hrpQo7M28/Xe1BprR7cY23TTMTpnOEBgi/NyZbuaJDQ4YhzVvuAk2kK55MijYP9qs96Sm29qiBtYoLe3czwVz0G61IpSt8z2qk6Ef13p6zRF3lxfko60XW9EcoWjI7FAolgizh1/EJDlTUsKtjqLol0ut+fnl19/+fr8669u5xfb9TLdbSkjqbXc7nlcsTdl1K0W+CGO4Zvzc0cmD9g6pDSRcaxqG6wYXLxnaI6wLvS2NlsKUyA61EWzrbVNZ+9Mp6X4sawp7Iy67uJki+CHuFw3u6ZL8bFw2JokJaL8aS2xfPW9Qd/nwxniGJ7v0EmwzUQ7kBumqQtWKJJr2pLcES5h24R1tlJxU9KEmli0RzbZwuVx5HWub6ACQYmJLNyykSMwWHL3Ng1F2Ry7yKuTo8effPhDxGPJb0ylcUzEryE4Et3YDxfU7GPfQO0Xebe3rZCGpdQdrVRUrd57g90x8ls5hxQ7Q8T+SdZjq87xLddHLdHisGaNJGuLeXyrE+mg6j3VByNQBeUvDl/EG1W8sQvLt1PR9+1YyHRGjsqals5kJuKwwbm8QcmjhpdVpRM60cu3cvLG5iKDmLApiIMVR0xUsIo7gWjooRxsqgYJyCAaHB8dL+aL9XLjGA5OyapgO4JITamyg0GI2gGLH2/PQdpohGiHpffqy5fUeW+oL44/KYpifTMvs7Kr2jAMS8twB1GpN/jxJ2ePA88v00wsLS2Vlo2GQ7IaCI2h0p44V9uDQTQ7mFKSviiyJKkoLJCjduDa5aogU4ippe0QMKL3OQY7DTol01CzDUbDIPCMztistqiEWmrStb/5x3+4vblGRoWsZzoZIwCjnJ0Mx1QhaGtZMuTuK7pkJ/EVb4HMYrOYI4o8fvp4PBrsdqj91h03bENWDFVMvZOTk6aoE6q6lAzMspIMba98+3DIo+rCfdWotGbUqEctyDc8WwRo2mNYBNFHYxZO4OSbZbFKA1xyJDGQpDyQ1bmeNZ5Nnj1/PxwONdssG4pleEHgO87F65cInBaZNxrVDpF64+YinqJSL3JcDr5riDRU08uaXpK4y4QliziDUO25GqjXmhVcdymqas21LM9xoyByWE0zBW6aCrkO8h2kNJ7rT8eT6WgaBiHVOSQQ6pSJMkeTWTgYSAu2Qw15fDw7OfaWqxhr74PnTyPffXQSKEKdqC8U4jVSijkJIx+Sq9VqtVgssM8Cz2Pup797EPjuNqP+Rs2n7SeL3Td9A/VvRkb9HhHz4OvBj0rL6GFg/I6h9H4W+FbL6k/9+g7zyLsvm3Xh4cyWIpCKu4h+kvPgrwhJROVSd1XZFrSM31gulgKTHjZ4iFznQsTPTCcjHDNZljmOW+AUyTNsBpx6o9EYTyWOkTuH2EFkq1H3zC4yMhmoB2g7lYxHfDcaREc3F3MsSrxOLTJ6RVUkWYJz7/TJyWAc2";

var image = document.createElement('img');
    image.src = base64blob;
    document.body.appendChild(image);

// It works.        
var myImg = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,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';
var image = document.createElement('img');
    image.src = myImg;
    document.body.appendChild(image);
```